# Python/pandas: Bar Chart with non-numerical categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following table:

```
song_ids                track_id    play_count_sum  user_id_count   genre_id
SOAAAMT12AB018C9C4  TRYIOYF12903CD4E73    1                1    Pop_Rock
SOAAAXN12A8C13A70C  TRXWDIG128F4274BF1    5                1    Latin
SOAABLP12A6D4F8861  TRXOSZE128F148A158    1                1    Pop_Rock
SOAABRT12A6D4F7940  TRUGBDI128F14548CD   13                2    International
SOAABVA12AC3DF673F  TRXVIGQ12903CE7F6E    4                3    Pop_Rock
```

I would like to create a bar chart by genre_id, but am failing, because it is not a numerical value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f=df.plot(df[['genre_id']].grouby(),df[['play_count_sum']].sum())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.plot` attribute for groupby object:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['genre_id'])['play_count_sum']
grouped.sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]